# Duplicate IDs in Local Collection when Meteor subscription changes

Tags: meteor, minimongo

Here's my scenario:

I have a collection of calendar events. Some events have a recurrence rule attached to them. When I subscribe to events in the client, I'm creating a new local collection called `LocalEvents`. I loop through all of my events that are published from the `Events` collection, and insert a new document in to my local collection for each occurrence of my event.

Here is my code with comments

```
//create reactive variable
const searchQuery = new ReactiveVar(null);

export default createContainer(({ params }) => {
    //subscribe to subscription passing the reactive var as the variable
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('Events.publications.admin.list.all', searchQuery.get());
    const loading = !subscription.ready();
    const allEvents = Events.find();

    //loop through cursor, if event recurs - create new document for the event and insert it in to LocalEvents collection
    allEvents.forEach(function(event) {
        if (event.eventRecurs) {
            //grab array of all recurring dates
            const dates = event.recurringDates;
            //loop through recurring dates and create new event document for each with a random ID and a parentId of the original event
            _.each(dates, (date) => {
                LocalEvents.insert({
                    '_id': Random.id(),
                    'name': event.name,
                    'description': event.description,
                    'defaultDate': date,
                    'parentId': event._id
                });
            })

        } else {
            //if event doesn't recur, set parentId and insert into local collection
            event.parentId = event._id;
            LocalEvents.insert(event);
        }
    });

    const events = LocalEvents.find({}, { sort: { defaultDate: 1 }}).fetch();
    //pass everything to the component
    return { loading, events, searchQuery };
}, AdminEventsAll);
```

My problem is that when my subscription changes (by using a search bar) - it seems that the local collection still holds some documents in it as there are repeated instances of the events. The argument I pass to my subscription (searchQuery) is set each time a key is pressed in a search bar in my UI - this creates a reactive search. As I type, for each letter I type I see the documents duplicate. It basically shows that the local collection is refilling with the same documents so they are repeating over and over again.

How can I ensure the collection is properly emptied in my container every time the searchQuery changes?

Thanks in advance

** EDIT - FOUND SOLUTION **

I added the solution I found as an answer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a similar problem, I managed to find a solution.

I added

```
Tracker.autorun(function(allEvents) {
    LocalEvents.remove({});
});
```

Now, anytime the cursor from the subscription changes (for example when a user searches and changes the `searchQuery` reactive var), the Tracker function will clear the Local Collection and then it will be repopulated.